# Are double negatives proper English (e.g. "I don't know nothing")?

Tags: grammaticality, negative-concord

I have heard many (rather most) people, especially in the USA, saying:

> I don't know nothing about it.

Is that correct? I always get a weird feeling hearing this and feel the correct one would be saying:

> I don't know anything about it.

Comment: This construction calls to mind Prissy's line from GWTW: Lawzy, we got to have a doctor. I don't know nothin' 'bout birthin' babies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second one is correct for most dialects of English. The first one is a double negative, or as we call it in linguistics, exhibits negative concord.  Wikipedia has a pretty good article on double negatives:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negative

Most prescriptive grammarians will tell you that a double negative is incorrect because it is "illogical." However, there are many languages that operate just fine using double negative obligatorily. For instance, almost all Romance languages have obligatory negative concord:

- **Italian:** Non so niente.
- **French:** Je ne sais pas.

Double negatives *used* to be grammatical in English, but there was a grammatical change sometime during Middle English. The Wikipedia article gives a sentence from a 1644 letter by Oliver Cromwell (emphasis is added by me).

> A little after, he said one thing lay upon his spirit. I asked him what it was. He told me it was that God had **not** suffered him to be **no more** the executioner of His enemies.

The double negative is still used in many modern dialects, but it is typically very stigmatized.

Comment: Could you check your first paragraph again: "The second one is a double negative" – isn't the *first* example the one with double negative?

Comment: oops! Fixed it.

Comment: French translation should be "Je ne sais rien". "Je ne sais pas" is simply "I don't know" (en) or "Non so" (it).

Answer (score 1):

The *New Oxford American English* reports that *anything* is used

- in negative, or questions to refer to a thing, no matter what.

  > Has she found anything?
  >   Nobody was saying anything.
- without negative, for emphasis.

  > Albert was ready for anything.

*Nothing* is used in sentences like

> She said nothing.
>   There's nothing we can do.
>   They found nothing wrong.

Using *nothing* (which means *not anything*) in a sentence with a negative is using a double negation. I imagine the double negation can be used in some particular cases to give emphasis to the sentence.

The *NOAD* has also the following note (reported in the *Oxford Living Dictionaries* for [*double negative*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/double_negative)) about the usage of double negatives.

> In practice this sort of double negative is widespread in dialect and other non-standard usage and rarely gives rise to confusion as to the intended meaning. Double negatives are standard in certain other languages such as Spanish and they have not always been unacceptable in English, either. The double negative was normal in Old English and Middle English and did not come to be frowned upon until some time after the 16th century, when attempts were made to relate the rules of language to the rules of formal logic. Modern (correct) uses of the double negative give an added subtlety to statements: saying *I am not unconvinced by his argument* suggests reservations in the speaker's mind that are not present in its ‘logical’ equivalent: *I am convinced by his argument*. According to standard English grammar, a double negative used to express a single negative, such as *I don't know nothing* (rather than *I don't know anything*), is incorrect. The rules dictate that the two negative elements cancel each other out to give an affirmative statement, so that *I don't know nothing* would be interpreted as *I know something*.

Comment: I don't think double negation typically has anything to do with emphasis. Some dialect have obligatory negative concord, and others don't.

Comment: @JoFrhwld: That is why I wrote _I imagine._

Comment: Don't NEVER say you can't use double negation for emphasis!

Answer (score 0):

The second example is the grammatically correct one.

However, the first is common in certain dialects.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes double negatives have legitimate uses.

> **A :** You wasted my time! I told you to look for serial downvotes. You searched for hours, and **you found nothing!**
>
> **B : No, I didn't find nothing!** I found a single upvote. Good enough?
>
> **A :** Oh, you donkey slap!

It's true that B "didn't find nothing."

Answer (score -1):

The correct one is the second. The first one might be used, for instance, by the (educated) speakers just in order to give their speach a pleasant rustic flavor. It sounds even better with "ain't" instead of "don't".

Comment: I disagree on two counts: (1) I find it hard to believe that someone who doesn't normally speak like this would use the phrase in order to sound "rustic". (2) "Ain't" normally means "is not" or "am not", so can't be used here.

Comment: Properly rustic would be pronounced as follows "I dunno nuffin abou' it, guv'nor" :)

Comment: Also, "rustic" implies "rural", i.e. used in the countryside. However, this kind of usage is also present in some London dialects, and London would be unlikely to be described as "rustic"!

Comment: @Melnikoff: no implication, since the word has MORE than one meaning. Also, "ain't" has more than two meanings: e.g. "haven't":

<i> "I ain't got no clothes left," she replied. "They stole my blue and the yellow cambric with muslin sleeves my lady gave me."</i> (Patrick O'Brian).

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff - "I find it hard to believe that someone who doesn't normally speak like this would use the phrase in order to sound "rustic". " There are segments of American society in which using precise English is perceived as a hostile act. Specifically, it is construed as an attempt to establish the speaker as superior to those around him. It's like the story about George Bush in his early political days, when he lost an argument and swore that he would never again be "out-Bubba'd".

Answer (score -1):

Logically speaking, the negative of negative is positive.

So, the first sentence may be translated as follows:

I don't know nothing = I know something

Nevertheless, some american slangs use this formula to strengthen the negation not to negate the negation!

Comment: I think this assumes language is parenthesizeable, so that "I don't know nothing" = "I don't (know nothing)". However, as many note, we really can't treat linguistic statements as straight mathematical statements. For example, "hot dog" is a single word, not a warm canine.