# What is the meaning of this sentence? I ain't worried 'bout nothin'

Tags: meaning

I ain't worried 'bout nothin'

I want to know the meaning of this line. I found it in a song named fifth harmony.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are double negatives proper English eg "I don't know nothing"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2232/are-double-negatives-proper-english-e-g-i-dont-know-nothing)

Comment: "I ain't worried 'bout nothin'" has a meaning that has nothing to do with typical "double-negative". "You are worried 'bout nothin" means "You are worried, but there is nothing to worry about". "I ain't worried 'bout nothin'" can very well mean "I'm worried, and I have a good reason to be worried", totally different from the "double-negative" meaning "I don't worry about anything".

Answer (score 0):

It is a common contraction and "corruption" of English. Actually one of a sociolect as pointed out. *Ain't* is the same as *am not* or *aren't*. and as the comment correctly points out *'bout* is a contraction of *about*. It is not far from accurate in its usage since *nuthin'* here, a contraction of *nothing*, is used to mean *anything*. Such double negatives are usually a product of a smaller vocabulary or at least a more casual use of words.

Comment: corruption of English is a misnomer here. There are many sociolects, and this is one of 'em.